# db connection with schema.tableName

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

My query is

```
 select* from "Table"."SampleDB";
```

My Java code is

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/Table.SampleDB";
            String user = "postgres";
            String pass = "pass";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
```

I am not able to connect to the database. How to call a "schema.TableName" in servlet getConnection. Please help me fix the issue.

Comment: A jdbc connection is against a _database_, not a table. You didn't tell us what the name of your database is. The correct syntax for the JDBC url is documented here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html  The "names" in your query are also wrong. A table is referenced using `schema_name.table_name`, ***not*** `table_name.database_name`

Comment: You forgot to tell what exactly happens instead. Which exception do you get, if any? A good exception in turn usually already represents the whole answer to your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use this :

```
String dbName=DB_NAME;//The name of DB
String user = "postgres";
String pass = "pass";
String dbURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/"+ dbName;

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
```

Or this :

```
 Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection connection = null;
    String dbName=DB_NAME;//The name of DB
    String user = "postgres";
    String pass = "pass";
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
       "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/"+dbName,user,pass);
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: You don't connect to a table in JDBC - you connect to a _database_.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name According to the query in the Question, the name of the dataBase is Table.No? If No, please can enlighten me?